# How to create a shapefile from xy in .csv file?

Tags: qgis, csv, import

I find many difficult to create a new shapefile in a new project following [those steps](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/import_csv.php).

I think the .csv file is correct (there are only: ID, X coord, Y coord) but when I would create the shapefile it gives me an error: "records not imported because of invalid geometry". What does it mean?

I have the same error woth the file downloaded from [this sample](http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/19-beginner-quantum-gis-tutorials/59-how-to-create-a-shapefile-from-xy-data-using-qgis.html).

In the picture below you can see the step before the given error:

[image: import_csv]

Comment: How do your x and y coordinates look like?

Comment: @Iris as you can see from the uploaded image the coordinates seems in the right format, aren't them?

Comment: In general the coordinates are correct, however, I am not familier with QGIS in particular

Comment: Do you have any coordinates that have a non numeric character or multiple decimals?

Comment: @artwork21 It seems not, it does import any data

Comment: i'm not a qgis user, but is there a possibility of different type of coordinate systems used in your point feature and the map you want to import them to?

Comment: @Joseph that's it. I was almost sure it was unchecked...if you reply in the box I will accept your post

Comment: @Ale - Awesome, glad it worked! Will post it as an answer for the convenience of others =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck the **"Coordinate GMS"** option which I believe in English is *"DMS coordinates"*. The csv file you linked to is not in `degrees/minutues/seconds` but in `XY` coordinates.

Unchecking this option should let you import the csv as a point shapefile.